# Why non-negative regression?

Tags: regression, regularization

I've seen this as regularization technique: impose that the coefficients are non-negative. When is this a good idea? What's the intuition and logic behind it?

Comment: Can you say where you've seen this? What was the context?

Comment: I don't remember. Just as a general approach to model design and applying regularization.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense as a general approach to regularization.  Are you sure you are not thinking of the lasso, where the absolute value of the coefficients is used in a penalty term?

Comment: I am. There is a thing called non-negative least squares.

Comment: Its misleading to call it regularisation, it is just adding prior knowledge.  Eg if you were trying to recover item  prices from total cost and item amounts you would impose that item prices are nonnegative using nonnegative least squares

Comment: I don't think it's misleading. What is regularization if not adding prior knowledge to your model estimation?

Answer (score 2):

This is adding prior knowledge to your model, in a somewhat Bayesian sense. Per the comments, not everyone would call this "regularization". I would, because it constrains the parameters to not vary wildly all over the place, just in a different way than (say) L1 or L2 regularization.

When does this make sense? Anytime we are sure that a regression coefficient *should* be positive, but because of the uncertainties involved, an unconstrained model might fit a negative one. For example:

- As [seanv507 writes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/153962/why-non-negative-regression#comment293526_153962), if we want to estimate item prices from total costs and item amounts, it makes sense to impose positive prices.
- I do retail sales forecasting. We typically constrain promotion effects to be positive, and price effects to be negative.
- Similarly, you may have cannibalization effects, which are typically very noisy and therefore prime candidates for any kind of regularization. If there is a promotion on Coca-Cola, we would expect Pepsi sales to go down, so in a model for Pepsi sales that includes promotions on Coca-Cola, we would constrain these coefficients to be negative (or at least non-positive).

Yes, often you can make a case that the opposite sign of the coefficient could be *possible*. However, usually this involves rather tortuous logic, and you often find that constraining parameters makes for better models and predictions in the vast majority of cases, even if you will always find isolated cases that would have profited from unconstrained parameters.